# Shiny R extract data from text file inputed by user

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a simple app that is supposed to ask for 1 (or more) unstructured  text files, given by the user with `fileInput`. These files have all the same structure.
The idea is to make the cleaning/extraction on the background and give back the clean data to the user (ideally into a table).

I am fairly new using Shiny and the examples I have found basically indicate how to proceed when the file input is already in a clean and structured way.

Here is a simplified code that illustrates what I have done so far:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = h2("Title", align = "left")),

    sidebarLayout(position = "left",

        sidebarPanel(h3("Data management window", align = "center"),       

            fileInput(inputId = "file_1",
                label = "Select file 1")
            ),

mainPanel(
  uiOutput(outputId = "tb")
  )
)))
```

And here the server side:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    input_file_1 <- reactive({
       if(is.null(input$file_1)){
           return("!! No data loaded !!")
          }
       readLines(input$file_1$datapath)
     })

     output$data_1 <- renderText({
         fileText_1 <- paste(input_file_1(), collapse = "\n")
     })

output$tb <- renderUI({

    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Window 1",
           br(),
           tags$div(
             tags$p("Summary infos : "),
             tags$ul(
               tags$li("Date calculation : ", Sys.Date()),

               tags$li("Info 1: "),

               tags$li("Info 2 : "),

               tags$li("Info 3 : "),
           br(),
           verbatimTextOutput("data_1"))
           ))
  )
  })

  })
```

At this stage I have managed to render the text of the file into the app. What I would like to do is to show in `tabPanel` some results obtained from the data extracted from the text file, like in the case of `Sys.Date()` but using values from the input file.

Do you have any ideas on how to proceed? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: It is a bit broad. Do you want a table, maybe graphics? You should be more specific.

Comment: @MLavoie you are right. Let say that in a first attempt I would like simply to extract some piece of information from the text file and  give it back after the   relative utml `tags$li("Info 1: ")` piece of code. No graphics for the moment, just values extracted from the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still too general, please more specific. But here is something to get you started. Using your `server` file and the `iris` dataset to make it easier, you can use the renderText() expression to extract the summary of one of your variable. And then you just add `textOutput()` expression in your `tags$li("Info 1: ")` argument.

Following a comment from OP, you could add a `selectInput()` that could help you pick one variable you want to summarise or extract information from. The code work as it is. Just replace iris by the file you will be loading.

```
   ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = h2("Title", align = "left")),

    sidebarLayout(position = "left",

                  sidebarPanel(h3("Data management window", align = "center"),       

                               fileInput(inputId = "file_1",
                                         label = "Select file 1"),
                               uiOutput("Variable")
                  ),

                  mainPanel(
                    uiOutput(outputId = "tb")
                  )
    ))


  server = function(input, output) {
    input_file_1 <- reactive({
      if(is.null(input$file_1)){
        return("!! No data loaded !!")
      }
      readLines(input$file_1$datapath)
    })

    output$data_1 <- renderText({
      fileText_1 <- paste(input_file_1(), collapse = "\n")
    })


    output$Variable <- renderUI({
      obj2 <- iris #replace by input_file_1()
      selectInput("Variable", "Choose a variable", as.list(colnames(obj2)), multiple = FALSE)
    })

    output$summary1 <- renderPrint({

      sub <- iris %>% select(input$Variable) #replace iris
      a <- max(sub)
      a

    })

    output$tb <- renderUI({

      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Window 1",
                 br(),
                 tags$div(
                   tags$p("Summary infos : "),
                   tags$ul(
                     tags$li("Date calculation : ", Sys.Date()),

                     tags$li("Info 1: ", textOutput("summary1")),

                     tags$li("Info 2 : "),

                     tags$li("Info 3 : "),
                     br(),
                     verbatimTextOutput("data_1"))
                 ))
      )
    })

  }
```

Comment: Thanks @MLavoie. I understand. The thing is that the `iris` data frame has a nice data frame structure while my file are unstructured and I have to scrap them to get the data I want in order to show them to the user. When I have a nice data frame I have no problem to extract information. Here however my user will upload a text file that must be scanned for data. This data will be combined via some functions, and finally showed as an output. For instance, let us say that one of the info is stored in the 1025th line of the text file and I want to show it in `Info 1:`. How should I proceed?

Comment: After some struggle I finally did manage to find a solution that works for me. I defined a number of functions before the server and I called them reactively from within the server. Thanks for the help and time. Cheers.